# Formik custom color picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

i'm trying to create a custom color picker with formik form

the probleme her is that parent component color are not changed :

```
import {SketchPicker} from "react-color";

export const MyColorPicker = ({label, ...props}) => {
  // with useField is should not use onChange but i get an error without defining it myself
  const [field] = useField(props);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#333");
  const handleChange = color => {
    setColor(color.hex);
    field.onChange(color.hex);
  };
  const onComplete = color => {
    setColor(color.hex);
    field.onChange(color.hex);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{padding: 10}}>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <SketchPicker {...props} {...field} color={color} onChange={handleChange} onChangeComplete={onComplete} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

as exemple this work :

```
export const MyTextAreaField = ({label, ...props}) => {
const [field, meta] = useField(props);

  if (field && field.value === null) {
    field.value = "";
  }
  return (
    <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
      <label className="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiFormLabel-filled">
        {label}
      </label>

      <TextareaAutosize
        rows={10}
        {...field}
        {...props}
        style={{marginTop: 10, fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue", fontSize: 15}}
      />
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? <div className="error">{meta.error}</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

- and parent code :

  ```
  <Formik
    initialValues={{
      data: { title :'', shortDescription:'', description:'', color:'')
    }}
    onSubmit={values => {
     console.log(values.data) ; // data.color stay null 
    }}>
    <Form>
       <MyTextAreaField id="data.description" name="data.description" label={t("PROJECT.DESCRIPTION")} />

       <MyColorPicker id="data.color" label={t("PROJET.COLOR")} name="data.color" />
    </Form>
  </Formik>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

finally i ended doing something like this :

In parent Component :

```
<MyColorPicker
     label={t("PROJECT.COLOR")}
     onChange={color => {
         data.project.color = color;
     }}
  />
```

Component definition

```
export const MyColorPicker = ({label, onChange}) => {   
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#333");      
  const handleChange = color => {
    setColor(color.hex);
  };
  return (
    <div
      style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "flex-start", alignItems: "center", padding: 10}}>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <ChromePicker color={color} onChange={handleChange} onChangeComplete={color=> onChange(color.hex) } />
    </div>
    )     
})
```